# R56 mini cooper turbo sounds

Tags: turbocharger, mini-cooper

I have a 2010 mini with a r56. the loss of power light comes on when I step on it. I know the PCV valve is bad on it and can set this light. I also have a rear main seal leak so the turbo has to come of, 160k miles on it and has a ticking noise should I while it's off replace it or does the turbo make any noise already? Another route is turbo rebuild and clean. Possibility? And any video of pulling the r56 for reference would be helpful I've been looking online there is not a lot of help in that Era of mini.

Comment: [Do you haz teh codez?](http://meta.mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/1473/675)

Comment: There are no codes just loss off power light

Comment: loss of power light/reduced power light generally have to do with the electronic throttle system. I would inspect the throttle assembly and clean it if necessary. Be careful not to move the throttle plate by hand. You also may want to watch pids when the problem occurs paying attention to MAP and ECT.

Comment: The throttle body has been and is clean I've got to replace the valve cover at a cost of $330 the PCV valve takes a poop and sets the light the main question is the turbo making noise I needed to know if it makes any noise at all and what kind if it does as well what kind of miles do you get out of them

Comment: I'm having a lot of issues understanding your question and comments.  Can you go in and add some punctuation?  Some commas could go a long way.  Perhaps break out your questions and ask them clearly and simply.  IDK, want to help ya out but just brutal trying to figure out what your saying.

Comment: Voting to close, question isn't well defined and no activity for the last five months.

Comment: @Michael no one is being snooty, we simply can't understand what exactly you're asking.The more effort you put into your question, the higher the chance someone will be able to answer it! Do edit it to make it more clear and as specific as possible and you will definitely get help if you still have your problem. If not - do post an answer how you solved it, we'd love to know.

Comment: For anyone who comes here in the future, I had similar symptoms on my 2008 R56 and it was torn blow-off valve. Ran fine until I really engaged the turbo, and then I got kicked into low power mode. Cost a few hundred bucks to fix at the dealer. https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/54988/mini-cooper-limp-mode-without-a-cel?rq=1